# Los datos serializados no se cargan aunque existan datos en Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, serialización

En mi proyecto uno de los mayores problemas los llevo teniendo con el sistema de guardado, hice un sistema de guardado serializable para guardan unos valores *los cuales son estáticos* y están en un archivo **DontDestroyOnLoad**, mientras creo una partida por primera vez los datos se conservan *quizás porque son variables estaticas, pero me gusta pensar que el sistema de guardado guarda bien*, el caso va cuando después de guardar (e insisto que funciona ya que cuando lo hago se crea el archivo con lo datos), pero al cargar vuelve a los valores por defecto, quizás no estoy modificando los datos que debería modificar en el script serializable, este luce así:

```
public class UIsettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static UIsettings Instance;
    //Data to save.
    public static string AirlineName = "Unknow";
    public static string UserName = "Unknow";
    public static int Mode = 0;
    public static int Hub = 0;
    //Autoload.
    public bool StartupLoad;

    void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        
    }
    void Start()
    {
        if (StartupLoad)
        {
            Load();
        }
    }
    //Guardar
    public void Save()
    {
        BinaryFormatter fb = new BinaryFormatter(); //Helper
        FileStream userData = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.dat"); //FileData route to create.
        UserMainData USERDATA = new UserMainData(); //Data to Serializar 

        //Data into the files.
        USERDATA.AirlineName = AirlineName;
        USERDATA.UserName = UserName;
        USERDATA.Mode = Mode;
        USERDATA.Hub = Hub;

        //Serializer
        fb.Serialize(userData, USERDATA);
        userData.Close();

        print("Saved"); //Process Ready Notification.
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.dat")) //Verify if exit a Saved.
        {
            BinaryFormatter fb = new BinaryFormatter(); //Helper
            FileStream userData = File.OpenRead(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.dat"); //Read the load.
            UserMainData USERDATA = new UserMainData(); //Data to deserializate.

            USERDATA = fb.Deserialize(userData) as UserMainData; //Data go to be de actual data.
            
            //Data loaded.
            USERDATA.AirlineName = AirlineName;
            USERDATA.UserName = UserName;
            USERDATA.Mode = Mode;
            USERDATA.Hub = Hub;

            print("Loaded"); //Process Ready Notification.
        }
        else
        {
            print("Cannot found existing game");
        }
    }
    public void NewGame()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.dat")) //Verify if exit a Saved.
        {
            File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.dat"); //Erase file.
        

        //Reestart data.
        AirlineName = "Unknow";
        UserName = "Unknow";
        Mode = 0;
        Hub = 0;

        print("Erased"); //Process Ready Notification.
        }else { print("Cannot found existing game"); }
    }
}
[Serializable()] //Data ready to Serializar
public class UserMainData : System.Object
{
    public string AirlineName;
    public string UserName;
    public int Mode;
    public int Hub;
}
```

y cuando me refiero a que estoy modificando lo que no debo lo digo porque busco cambiar los valores de

```
public static string AirlineName = "Unknow";
public static string UserName = "Unknow";
public static int Mode = 0;
public static int Hub = 0;
```

además de que lo referencio desde otro scripts para leerlos y modificarlos así;

```
print(UIsettings.AirlineName);
print(UIsettings.UserName);
print(UIsettings.Mode);
print(UIsettings.Hub);
```

pienso también que se pueden estar guardando son los valores por defecto o algo parecido, y que además también la referencia a ellos para conseguir sus valores en otros scripts también están mal. Llevo tiempo en mi proyecto, esto es un feo altibajo que aun no logro arreglar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente el problema que veo con tu codigo es que estás usando las mismas instrucciones tanto en el `Load()` como en el `Save()`:

```
USERDATA.AirlineName = AirlineName;
USERDATA.UserName = UserName;
USERDATA.Mode = Mode;
USERDATA.Hub = Hub;
```

Entiendo que en el `Save()`, si se tiene que respetar esta estructura, pero en el `Load()` deberías poner las asignaciones al revés, ya que deserializas pero estás aplicando los valores por defecto a lo que has deserializado. Tendría que quedarte así:

```
public void Save()
{
    BinaryFormatter fb = new BinaryFormatter(); //Helper
    FileStream userData = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.dat"); //FileData route to create.
    UserMainData USERDATA = new UserMainData(); //Data to Serializar 

    //Data into the files.
    USERDATA.AirlineName = AirlineName;
    USERDATA.UserName = UserName;
    USERDATA.Mode = Mode;
    USERDATA.Hub = Hub;

    //Serializer
    fb.Serialize(userData, USERDATA);
    userData.Close();

    print("Saved"); //Process Ready Notification.
}
public void Load()
{
    if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.dat")) //Verify if exit a Saved.
    {
        BinaryFormatter fb = new BinaryFormatter(); //Helper
        FileStream userData = File.OpenRead(Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.dat"); //Read the load.
        UserMainData USERDATA = new UserMainData(); //Data to deserializate.

        USERDATA = fb.Deserialize(userData) as UserMainData; //Data go to be de actual data.
        
        //Data loaded.
        AirlineName = USERDATA.AirlineName;
        UserName = USERDATA.UserName;
        Mode = USERDATA.Mode;
        Hub = USERDATA.Hub;

        print("Loaded"); //Process Ready Notification.
    }
    else
    {
        print("Cannot found existing game");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenias razón, allí estaba el problema, cambiando los valores ya reconoce los datos correctamente, admito qué estaba algo desesperanzado por eso, pero vuelvo a tener ánimos, Gracias @Marc! Te debo mucho.